# libnet.h no such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, centos7, libnet

So, I'm trying to compile my C code using the command "gcc -o file file.c", but I get "error: libnet.h: No such file or directory" I included libnet.h (#include ) and I also installed libnet. I'm running CentOS 7.

Comment: Where/how did you install libnet?

Comment: You may have to specify `-I /path/to/libnet.h`

Comment: @ChrisTurner I installed it using the command "yum install libnet"

Comment: @Robert I don't know where is located.

Comment: Hi @Richardmikelson! Could you show us a minimum example of the code that you are trying to compile?

Comment: @Rocío I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum install libnet` only installs the precompiled library.

You need to install the headers using `yum install libnet-devel` before you can use it in your own software.